# can't push subtree branch

Tags: git

I have a git repository containing an application, and I want to use a subdir of that repo to update a shared library repository.  I can fetch the library repo, commit an update, but I cannot make it push that commit back to the remote.  It should be a fast-forward, but it says it is not.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$ git remote add lib goertzen@minerva:/pub/shared_git_repositories/lib.git

$ git fetch
From minerva:/pub/shared_git_repositories/lib
 * [new branch]      master     -> lib/master

$ git checkout -b libmaster lib/master
Branch libmaster set up to track remote branch master from lib.
Switched to a new branch 'libmaster'

$ git merge --squash -s subtree -X theirs master
Auto-merging lib.yaml
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested

$ git commit -m "blah blah blah"
[libmaster 4949ef3] blah blah blah
 1 files changed, 148 insertions(+), 95 deletions(-)

$ git push lib
To goertzen@minerva:/pub/shared_git_repositories/lib.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'goertzen@minerva:/pub/shared_git_repositories/lib.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

$ git pull
Already up-to-date.

$ git log --graph --all --full-history --branches --decorate
* commit 4949ef3181c21d85340b9fb16af5f9c2c58e75ae (HEAD, libmaster)
| Author: <snip>
| Date:   Tue Mar 8 15:25:03 2011 -0600
|
|     minitransfer changes
|
* commit e2dca9e2bcd28d09a455e9cc662f7eb630a0adc2 (lib/master)
  Author: <snip>
  Date:   Thu Feb 24 10:54:31 2011 -0600

      initial commit of shared lib repo

* commit b70bde69e5c4ddb079d06d7310d415fa89764b95 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
| Author: <snip>
| Date:   Fri Mar 4 15:41:05 2011 -0600
|
|     fix typo
|
* commit cc64b565fbb88729e16314f76867ab24c37bfc47
| Author: <snip>
| Date:   Fri Mar 4 15:38:59 2011 -0600
|
...
```

I can replace the squashed subtree merge with a trivial edit, and I still have the same issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out "git push lib" was actually trying to push libmaster to origin/master instead of lib/master (I experimented on some sacrificial repos).  When I spelled it all out in detail like this...

```
git push lib libmaster:master
```

...it worked.

I would of course like to be able to push without having to spell it out in detail.  This leaves me wondering if I brought lib into the repo in an odd way, or if I need to configure the branch somehow.  I have some reading to do...

Comment: `git push remote` defaults to pushing “matching” branches. You expected it to push to the tracked (a.k.a. upstream) branch. You can configure this with the `push.default` configuration variable (see *[git-config(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)*).

Comment: It is a bit unusual to have “unrelated” remotes/branches in a single repository (i.e. those that do not have some bit of the history DAG in common). There is some precedent (GitHub `gh-pages` branches, git.git’s `man` and `html` branches), but most cases do not share content. The (some)-related-content-but-no-shared-history relationship that your `master` (apparently) has to `lib/master` is probably even more unusual.
You might be interested in [`git subtree`](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree).

Comment: Thanks Chris, push.default=tracking is what I'm looking for.  I naively followed subtree merging directions from Pro-Git which results in unrelated branches.  This caused problems when I wanted to subtree merge code from one to the other since there was no merge basis.  I now understand how to connect the histories and will do so for my projects.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks to you -- saved me a headache after a night of toiling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Do as Git says and run `git pull` first...

Comment: It says "Already up-to-date".  There is nobody else working on these repos.